# Python csv read and write, (write only saves last row)

Tags: python-3.x

I'm a little stuck right now,
i have the script below, it opens a csv from the supplier and makes an correct csv for import in my system. However, it only saves the last row given from velleman64993.csv.

I thought to keep the "open" outside anything and also the "for record in records:"

```
import csv
import io
filename = "Vellemantest.csv"
headers = "ID, Verkooprijs, \n"
f = io.open(filename, "w", encoding="utf-8")
f.write(str(headers))

#resultaten opslaan in een record.
records = []

#De resultaten uit de feed halen en verwerken
with open('Velleman64993.csv', 'r') as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter = ';')
    for row in reader:
        artikel = (row[0])
        prijs = (row[4])
        #Standaard een basis array
    if artikel:
        records.append((artikel, prijs))

for record in records:
        #Schrijf de resultaten naar de csv file
    f.write(str(record[0]) + ", " + str(record[1]) + "\n")
    print(row[0] , row[4])
f.close()

if f.close:
    print('CSV opgeslagen')
else:
    print('Er is een fout opgetreden met het opslaan')
```

Comment: `if artikel: records.append((artikel, prijs))` should be in the `for` loop. Currently it is after it so only one thing gets added to the `records` list.

Comment: Wow so stupid but, so simple. 2 hours i was wandering over the code. Thx Dude!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

write function overwrites, when you open without "a" option. Do something like this,

```
f = io.open(filename, "a", encoding="utf-8") # not "w"
```

Comment: it looks like the OP reads from and writes to different files. the 'a'ppend option is only needed if the output file already exists and its content should not be overwritten but extended.

Comment: Indeed, i open a file from supplier and create a new one with my own style and options to import it in my system.